# Problem with mysql_query() ;Says resource expected 

Tags: php, mysql

I have this php file. The lines marked as bold are showing up the error :"mysql_query() expecets parameter 2 to be a resources. Well, the similar syntax on the line on which I have commented 'No error??' is working just fine.

```
 function checkAnswer($answerEntered,$quesId)
 {
  //This functions checks whether answer to question having ques_id = $quesId is satisfied by $answerEntered or not

  $sql2="SELECT keywords FROM quiz1 WHERE ques_id=$quesId";
  **$result2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);**
  $keywords=explode(mysql_result($result2,0));

  $matches=false;
  foreach($keywords as $currentKeyword)
  {
   if(strcasecmp($currentKeyword,$answerEntered)==0)
   {
    $matches=true;
   }
  }

  return $matches;

 }

 $sql="SELECT answers FROM user_info WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[user_id]";
 $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn);         // No error??
 $answerText=mysql_result($result,0);

 //Retrieve answers entered by the user
 $answerText=str_replace('<','',$answerText);
 $answerText=str_replace('>',',',$answerText);
 $answerText=substr($answerText,0,(strlen($answerText)-1));
 $answers=explode(",",$answerText);

 //Get the questions that have been assigned to the user.
 $sql1="SELECT questions FROM user_info WHERE user_id = $_SESSION[user_id]";
 **$result1=mysql_query($sql1,$conn);**
 $quesIdList=mysql_result($result1,0);
 $quesIdList=substr($quesIdList,0,(strlen($quesIdList)-1));
 $quesIdArray=explode(",",$quesIdList);



 $reportCard="";
 $i=0;
 foreach($quesIdArray as $currentQuesId)
 {
  $answerEnteredByUser=$answers[$i];

  if(checkAnswer($answerEnteredByUser,$currentQuesId))
  {
   $reportCard=$reportCard+"1";
  }
  else
  {
   $reportCard=$reportCard+"0";
  }
  $i++;
 }

 echo $reportCard;
?>
```

Here is the file connect.php. It is working just fine for other PHP documents.

```
<?php
 $conn= mysql_connect("localhost","root","password");
 mysql_select_db("quiz",$conn);
?>
```

Comment: I marked the lines as bold but sadly it didn't come up. The error causing lines are marked within a pair of **.

Comment: At which point are you including connect.php?

Comment: You should always check query results for errors. Even if the SQL itself is fine, there's far too many other reaons for queries to fail to NOT check for error conditions. At least do an `... or die(mysql_error())` after each query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$conn isn't declared as a global so the function cannot access it, as it is not defined within it.

Either simply add

```
global $conn;
```

To the top of the function to allow it to access the $conn.

Or you can remove $conn from the mysql_query() statement. By default it will use the current connection (as mentioned in the comments below).

Comment: Or you can remove `$conn` from the `mysql_query()` statement.  By default it will use the current connection.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am a beginner in PHP and I still have the habit of forgetting that global variables are not available in functions in PHP, unlike C. THanks a lot.

Answer (score 5):

```
$result2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn);
```

$conn is not defined in the scope of your function (even if you're including the connect.php file before that.

although you can use the suggestion to make $conn **global**, it's usually better practice to not make something global just for the sake of globalizing it.

i would instead pass $conn to the function as a parameter.  this way, you can reuse the same function you wrote with different connections.

Comment: thanks a lot. I am a beginner in PHP and I still have the habit of forgetting that global variables are not available in functions in PHP, unlike C. THanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Where do you set $conn?  It doesn't look like you set a connection within that function